# Random number generator in C++

Tags: random-number-generator

I've wrote a simple random number generater in C++.

Simply, I thought, the random things in software. I wrote it based on below:

1. When an object is created on the stack, its address is random.
2. The address of the static variable created in the template is fixed but unpredictable, aka, random.
3. The physical memory address where the kernel loads the program is random. (exactly unpredictable, not intended random)
4. Finally, the higher complexity of the software, the stack addresses are allocated more randomly.

```
    namespace _ {
        template<typename T>
        struct random_t {
            inline static uint32_t rand(size_t p) {
                static uint64_t k = uint64_t(0xabcdef1234567890ull);

                if (!k) {
                    k = size_t(&k) + p;

                    if (sizeof(p) != sizeof(uint64_t)) {
                        k |= (uint64_t(p) << 32);
                    }
                }

                int32_t r = (k += (p + ((k << 32) | (k >> 32))) >> 8) & 0xfffffffff;
                return int32_t(r < 0 ? -r : r);
            }

            inline static T rand(T _min, T _max, size_t p) {
                constexpr size_t _R = sizeof(T) / sizeof(uint32_t);
                uint32_t v[_R <= 0 ? 1 : _R] = { 0, };
                int32_t mul = (p % 4) + 1;

                for (size_t i = 0; i < _R * mul; ++i)
                    v[i % _R] += rand(p);

                return ((*((T*)v)) % (_max - _min)) + _min;
            }

            int32_t _n;
            T _c, _min, _max;

            random_t(T _min, T _max, int32_t _n) 
                : _n(_n), _c(0), _min(_min), _max(_max)
            {
                _c = rand(_min, _max, size_t(this));
            }

            inline random_t begin() const { return random_t(_min, _max, _n); }
            inline random_t end() const { return random_t(_min, _max, _n); }

            inline bool operator ==(const random_t& v) const { return !_n; }
            inline bool operator !=(const random_t& v) const { return _n; }

            inline random_t& operator ++() { --_n; _c = rand(_min, _max, size_t(this)); return *this; }
            inline random_t& operator --() { --_n; _c = rand(_min, _max, size_t(this)); return *this; }

            inline random_t operator ++(int) { return random_t(_min, _max, _n--); }
            inline random_t operator --(int) { return random_t(_min, _max, _n--); }

            inline T operator *() const { return _c; }
            inline operator T() const { return _c; }
        };
    }

    template<typename T> /* facade: */
    inline _::random_t<T> random(T _min, T _max, int32_t n = 1) { return _::random_t<T>(_min, _max, n); }
```

Usage:

```
    for (int r : random(100000, 999999, 10)) {
        printf("%d\n", r);
    }
```

So, Can this be really safe for cryptography?

Comment: We don't review code, or new designs, see what's on-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). On top of [poncho's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/88971/555): an irreparable issue is that assumptions 1/2/3/4 are wrong on many platforms with C++, including many modern embedded systems, and some PCs. For example, when compiling the code under `gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0` with no option and running repeatedly under `cmd.exe` of `Windows 10.0.19042.867 x64`, I always get the same output: 526833 364721 629443 258887 417774 735548 800970 670126 340254 580508.

Answer (score 3):

> So, Can this be really safe for cryptography?

No, it's quite awful; it doesn't even meet the criteria for a statistical random number generator.

This particular random generator will fairly quickly run into a loop of length 33; that is, after an initial sequence, it'll keep on repeating the same 33 numbers.  This can be easily seen by modifying your example code to produce 100 numbers rather than 10; several repeats will appear in the output.

The specific numbers that appear in the cycle will vary between runs - that would appear to be due to the initial conditions.

As for the more general question of whether you can use the random layout employed by most OS's (randomizing locations to try to make various hacks that depend on locations of various objects somewhat harder), well, I can't say that I'm all that thrilled with it - I'm not sure of the OS uses all that much entropy in randomizing locations (and of course, there's no good way to 'reseed' with fresh entropy without having the OS reload your software again); I would rather suggest relying on something like a RDRAND or RDSEED instruction...

Comment: A better suggestion is to at least start with the OS's CSPRNG. RDRAND/RDSEED can be horribly broken (AMD has screwed these up a few times, resulting in constant output) but OS CSPRNGs will tend to have other entropy sources as well, so they'll still provide good entropy.